# problem with openjpa query cache in glassfish + class cast exception form QueryKey

Tags: glassfish, openjpa, query-cache

Using openjpa 1.2.0 with it's built-in DataCache on Glassfish, enabling query cache and pin some named queires, We see the following exception:
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.openjpa.datacache.QueryKey

Anyone has any ideas?

Full exception dump:
[#|2011-05-01T11:43:05.728-0500|WARNING|sun-appserver9.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction|_ThreadID=30;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-20393-0;_RequestID=3ce3425f-cd4b-42b9-a305-570c5745add7;|JTS5054: Unexpected error occurred in after completion
 org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to org.apache.openjpa.datacache.QueryKey
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.afterCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:1870)
        at com.sun.jts.jta.SynchronizationImpl.after_completion(SynchronizationImpl.java:154)
        at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.RegisteredSyncs.distributeAfter(RegisteredSyncs.java:210)
        at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.TopCoordinator.afterCompletion(TopCoordinator.java:2585)
        at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.CoordinatorTerm.commit(CoordinatorTerm.java:433)
        at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.TerminatorImpl.commit(TerminatorImpl.java:249)
        at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.CurrentImpl.commit(CurrentImpl.java:623)
        at com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:309)
        at com.sun.enterprise.distributedtx.J2EETransactionManagerImpl.commit(J2EETransactionManagerImpl.java:1030)
        at com.sun.enterprise.distributedtx.J2EETransactionManagerOpt.commit(J2EETransactionManagerOpt.java:397)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:3792)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:3571)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.WebServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(WebServiceInvocationHandler.java:200)
        at $Proxy973.transfer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.InvokerImpl.invoke(InvokerImpl.java:81)
        at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.EjbInvokerImpl.invoke(EjbInvokerImpl.java:82)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:146)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:257)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:93)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:595)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.*doRun(Fiber.java:554)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:106)
        at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.MonitoringPipe.process(MonitoringPipe.java:147)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.*_doRun(Fiber.java:595)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.*doRun(Fiber.java:554)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:106)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.tx.service.TxServerPipe.process(TxServerPipe.java:317)
        at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:218)
        at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:129)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.*_doRun(Fiber.java:595)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:554)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:243)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:444)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:135)
        at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.handlePost(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:113)
        at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.invoke(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:87)
        at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.EjbWebServiceServlet.dispatchToEjbEndpoint(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:226)
        at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.EjbWebServiceServlet.service(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:155)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.AdHocContextValve.invoke(AdHocContextValve.java:114)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:571)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:571)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1080)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:571)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1080)
        at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:272)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:637)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:568)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:813)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:265)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to org.apache.openjpa.datacache.QueryKey
        at org.apache.openjpa.datacache.AbstractQueryCache.onTypesChanged(AbstractQueryCache.java:85)
        at org.apache.openjpa.datacache.DataCacheStoreManager.updateCaches(DataCacheStoreManager.java:252)
        at org.apache.openjpa.datacache.DataCacheStoreManager.commit(DataCacheStoreManager.java:90)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.commit(DelegatingStoreManager.java:94)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.endStoreManagerTransaction(BrokerImpl.java:1308)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.endTransaction(BrokerImpl.java:2177)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.afterCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:1846)
        ... 75 more
|#]

Answer (score 0):

After doing some debugging, I realized that generated query key is null because entities used in a named query are not data cache enabled.